# How to show and hide modal after ajax call in alpine js

Tags: modal-dialog, hide, show

```
    <code >
      <div x -data = "{ show: false }" ><button @click="show = !show" :
    aria - expanded = "show ? 'true' : 'false'" :class="{ 'active': show }" > Toggle Show</
    button ><div x -show = "show" > Hello world</div ></div >
   <code >
```

How can we change x-show value after we getting the ajax response alpinejs

Comment: Did you figure this out?